# Как удаленно перезапустить службу Windows

Tags: c#

Хочу написать сервис, который будет мониторить состояние служб на других серверах и в случае, если служба не пишет данные, её перезапускать. Чем можно воспользоваться?

Сервера win server 2000, win server 2003

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть вот [это](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/pstools)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Через WMI

```
//your_server - доменное имя или IP
//your_service - имя службы
// запуск
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "wmic /node:your_server service where name=\"your_service\" call startservice");
// остановка
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "wmic /node:your_server service where name=\"your_service\" call stopservice");
```

Comment: при запуске открывается командная строка и все, ничего не происходит

Comment: думаю и без консоли это сделать можно, напрямую. может проще даже батник запускать

Comment: @des1roer, проверь команду в консоли сначала. Да запускать cmd.exe необязательно, просто наглядней выглядит, поэтому так написал. можно запускать wmic.exe. Его закрывать, потом надо будет. Удобнее ли тебе таскать bat-ник не знаю, но смысла не вижу

Comment: в консоли все ок wmic /node:"proizvodstvo"  /user:"DOMEN\adminasutp" /password:"Vwm3jb33" service where name="srvc_control" call startservice

Answer (score 5):

можно winAPI воспользоваться. OpenSCManager иже с ними по MSDN, так и WMI

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

    public class MainWork
    {
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            public MainWork()
            {
                psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                psi.FileName = "cmd";               
            }
        public void Start()
        {     
            psi.Arguments = @"/k wmic /node:""proizvodstvo""  /user:""DOMEN\adminasutp"" /password:""Vwm3jb33"" service where name=""srvc_control"" call startservice";
            Process.Start(psi);
        }
        public void Stop()
        {      
            psi.Arguments = @"/k wmic /node:""proizvodstvo""  /user:""DOMEN\adminasutp"" /password:""Vwm3jb33"" service where name=""srvc_control"" call stopservice";
            Process.Start(psi);
            _timer.Stop();
        }
```

Comment: *Vwm3jb33* хороший пароль:)